# Why do I get "uninitialized constant" error when referencing a class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is how my data structure looks like

```
Controller
   API
      V1
         Controller1.rb
         Controller2.rb
         Serializers
            Model1Serializer.rb
            Model2Serializer.rb
```

I'm trying to access the serializers in my Controllers

Here is my Controller

```
class API::V1::Controller1 < ApplicationController

  require_relative 'model1_serializer'

   def doStuff
      render json:MyData, each_serializer:Model1Serializer
   end

end
```

Here is my serializer

```
class API::V1::Serializers::Model1Serializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   # Code here for serializing
end
```

I'm getting the following error. Why does it think Model1Serializer is under Controller 1?

**uninitialized constant API::V1::Controller1::Model1Serializer**

If In my Controller i change `Model1Serializer` to `API::V1::Serializers::Model1Serializer` then it works, except I don't want to be dependent on V1 in my namespace, that way If I decide to move the code to V2 I don't end up changing the code to point to V2. What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 5):

> "Why does it think Model1Serializer is under Controller 1:

Strictly speaking that is not actually the case. When looking up a constant, Ruby checks multiple namespaces (if they available) but the error message only mentions the innermost one.

> Why do I get “uninitialized constant” error when referencing a class?

To answer this, it is important to understand how Ruby looks up constants. Assuming you have this namespace hierarchy:

```
module API
  module V1
    class Controller1
    end
  end
end
```

If you are accessing `Model1Serializer` from `Controller1` Ruby checks the following nested namespaces:

1. `API::VI::Controller1::Model1Serializer`
2. `API::VI::Model1Serializer`
3. `API::Model1Serializer`
4. `::Model1Serializer`

But `Model1Serializer` is defined in `API::VI::Serializers::Model1Serializer` which is not included in this list. That is why Ruby can't find it.

To fix this, you should change the offending line to include the sub-module:

```
render json: MyData, each_serializer: Serializers::Model1Serializer
```

But most likely it still won't work because you are using "shortcut namespaces", i.e. `API::V1` instead of `module API; module V1; ...; end; end` This prevents Ruby from searching parent namespaces because they are not added to the nested modules list.

In other words, only the following namespaces are checked by Ruby:

1. `API::VI::Controller1::Serializers::Model1Serializer`
2. `::Serializers::Model1Serializer`

You can access the module hierarchy by calling `Module.nesting` at the desired code location.

Disclaimer: There is a lot more to Ruby constant lookup than presented here.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is `API::V1::Controller1`, but your serializer is `API::V1::Serializers::Model1Serializer`.

In your `doStuff` method, you try to look up `Model1Serializer` -- but there's no way to see that class from this point in the namespace.

Try using `API::V1::Serializers::Model1Serializer` instead there.

---

**Update:** The OP edited his question:

> If In my Controller i change Model1Serializer to API::V1::Serializers::Model1Serializer then it works, except I don't want to be dependent on the Vq in y namespace, that way If I decide to move the code to V2 I don't end up changing the code to point to V2. What's the best way to handle this?

A quick way is to define `Current = V1` in your API module, then reference `API::Current::...` when referencing your models from the controllers.

A better way is to think carefully about why you need to simultaneously provide multiple APIs in the same application like this, and whether that's really the right way to version it. (That's probably outside the scope of a single SO answer, though, and will be too dependent on your specific application.)

Comment: I updated my question, I rather not have any dependency on V1, any suggestions? Don't want to ho back and update my code to point to V2 when I create a new version